# Total function vs Partial function

Tags: order-theory

I'm reading a lecture note in which the following functions ($fact_i : \mathbb{Z}_\perp → \mathbb{Z}_\perp$) for $i \in \mathbb{N}$ are NOT considered total:

\begin{equation}
fact_0(x) = \perp \text{for all } x \in \mathbb{Z}_\perp
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
fact_1(x) \begin{cases}
   x!,     & \text{for } 0 \le x \lt 1 \\
   1       & \text{for } x \lt 0 \\
   \perp   & \text{for } x = \perp \text{or } 1 \le x
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
fact_2(x) \begin{cases}
   x!,     & \text{for } 0 \le x \lt 2 \\
   1       & \text{for } x \lt 0 \\
   \perp   & \text{for } x = \perp \text{or } 2 \le x
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

but the *least upper bound* of this chain $\sqcup \{fact_0,fact_1,fact_2, ...\}$ which is equal to the following:

\begin{equation}
fact(x) \begin{cases}
   x!,     & \text{for } 0 \le x \\
   1       & \text{for } x \lt 0 \\
   \perp   & \text{for } x = \perp \\
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

is considered TOTAL. I am confused as a total function must be defined for all inputs but I see no difference in $fact_1(x)$ and $ fact(x)$. Why one is considered total but not the other?

Comment: I don't know the $\perp$ notation - what does it mean ?

Comment: @TomCollinge, it's called bottom or least element.

Comment: Thanks. And if \begin{equation}
fact_0(x) = \perp \text{for all } x \in \mathbb{Z}_\perp
\end{equation} then what is it the least element of ?

Comment: @TomCollinge, least element of what?

Comment: That's my question: to say it's a least element suggests it's a least element of some set ?

Comment: Sorry I think I was wrong about bottom. This is [bottom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type).

Comment: Also [Bottom and Partial Functions](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Denotational_semantics#Bottom_and_Partial_Functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like we've used our ration of comments so I'll post this as a tentative answer.

I would guess that $f(\perp) = \perp$ doesn't detract from a function being total: it just says no input no output.

$fact(x) $ returns a value for all *x* other than $\perp$ whereas $fact_1(x)$ doesn't return values (returns $\perp$) for $x \ge 1$

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking of the same.